# Multiple API keys in the same Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, api-key

Is it possible to specify multiple keys for Google Maps Android API in the same code base?

It looks like I have to change the key in manifest file each time I change keystore. It's not very convenient, imho, if you need to test the app signed with keys form debug and release keystores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is what you want to do. You should add both debug and release SHA1 key to API key on Google Developer API Console. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141660/1120126)

Answer (score 3):

I added *both* keys in the manifest at once. Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ..
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <!-- RELEASE key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my-release-keu" />

        <!-- DEBUG key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my-debug-key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Apparently, this works. Looks like Google code is smart enough to use relevant key automatically.

Comment: This may sound weird but you have to put your keys in the **exact same order** as they are seen on API console page

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no programmatical form on doing this. For comodity, you can define API keys in strings.xml, and retrieve it from the manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
String debugMapKey   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String releaseMapKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

String mapKey = BuildConfig.DEBUG ? debugMapKey : releaseMapKey;

MapView mv = new MapView(this, mapKey);
```