# Android: automatically choose debug/release Maps v2 api key?

Tags: android, google-maps, key, android-manifest, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps v2 API in my project. In Google Maps v2 the debug/release API key is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I have seen [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029819/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-api-key) but in that map key is defined in a xml layout file not in `AndroidManifest.xml`. So can I define both debug and release keys for my project in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

I want something like this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

If debug mode:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/debug_map_api_key"/>
```

If release mode:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/release_map_api_key"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878249/how-to-configure-android-map-sdk-v2-to-use-different-keys-for-production-and-dev

Comment: I get the idea from this link. Thanks

Comment: @KiritVaghela hey kirit how you doing my friend? remember you solved my listview problem when i was developing cheatbook? but those suckers terminated my developer account

Comment: @JRE.exe do they provide specific reason for this termination? if so, post it here.

Comment: It takes 3 app suspensions to get your account terminated (no matter simultaneous or after some time) so first violation was description (which was not my fault) i wrote proper description with spaces but it removed all the spaces on its own leading to suspension. second is intellectual property (that's my only fault because i never new about such thing). third one was i made a chat app and it got suspended because of inappropriate behavior of users (how stupid of google for doing that). i write to them 3 times but they never replied. now planning to sell my phone for IOS account and app's fee

Comment: reason they provided is multiple violations of T&C. it was terminated this year in march when i was making 60k INR per month and that was just starting..

Comment: Easy and quickest solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39265698/1348522

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Using build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        buildConfigField("String", "map_api_key", "\"your debug map api key here\"")
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField("String", "map_api_key", "\"your release map api key here\"")
    }
}
```

I solved this issue using this steps:

In Google Developer API Console

1. Click on <kbd>Create New Android key...</kbd>
2. In cmd.exe/Terminal: `keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore`
3. Password: `android`
4. Now enter `SHA1 key;package name` for debug and press enter
5. Enter `SHA1 key;package name` for release
6. Click on <kbd>Create</kbd>

Now use this API key your project

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/common_map_api_key"/>
```

Comment: I did not know you could add multiple SHA1 key for a same package. Worked really good.

Comment: first SHA1 key using debug.keystore and secong SHA1 key using release.keysore. In my case it work in both debug apk and release api

Comment: The order of keys doesn't really matter.

Comment: @KiritVaghela Can we use different package name here. I want to bind 2 apps with single google project. is this possible?

Comment: Quick way to achieve in Android latest version http://stackoverflow.com/a/39265698/1348522

Answer (score 32):

## One of the Best way to use build.gradle file in latest Android 5.0 and Android 6.0, Android 9+ (API 20, 21,22,23, 24, 25,26, 27 28, 29)

Well you can use them simply without creating product flavors in `gradle`. This is another example we can achieve via `Gradle`. You can achieve it with two simple steps.

- Add custom value to `manifestplaceholders` build.gradle file.

See below

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapApiKeyValue:"GHjaSyAjlyp3O831lgaonHMXsd-_DpQ3002x3S4"]
    }

    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapApiKeyValue:"AIzaSyAuMGDLr2HeuRed4JA0CrdYYdZRjeC3EA"]
    }
}
```

- Edit manifest file like below.

part of my manifest file

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="${mapApiKeyValue}" />
```

This solution works for the latest Android 5.0 and  Android 6.0 (API 20, 21,22,23)

---

### Updated on 5/3/2018 for Xamarin Form and Xamarin Native Apps

Open   `AssemblyInfo.cs` in Android Project and addd the following code

```
#if DEBUG
   [assembly: MetaData("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY", Value = "DebugKey123123123")]
#else
   [assembly: MetaData("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY", Value = "ReleaseKey123123123")]
#endif
```

To Check the AndroidManifest file, goto `obj/Debug/android` folder and open the manifest file and check the meta info,

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="DebugKey123123123" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Really useful answer if you want to add some custom keys, not Google API.

Answer (score 16):

For organizations that need to maintain separate keys, you can place them in separate directories in Android Studio. Make sure the subdirectory of `src` you use matches a flavor or `buildType`

From [Building Your Project with Gradle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#workBuildVariants):

```
To build each version of your app, the build system combines source code and resources from:

src/main/ - the main source directory (common to all variants)
src/<buildType>/ - the build type source directory
src/<flavorName>/ - the flavor source directory
```

In `projectroot/yourapp/build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        runProguard false
        debuggable true

    }
    release {
        runProguard true
        debuggable false
        ...
    }
```

In `projectroot/yourapp/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
...
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">
<!-- Don't put your key here -->
...
```

In `projectroot/yourapp/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`, fully qualify the name of the app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:name="com.hipmunk.android.HipmunkApplication">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="yourdebugkey" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In `projectroot/yourapp/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:name="com.hipmunk.android.HipmunkApplication">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="release key" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using gradle you can do the following:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  .. .. ...
    buildTypes {
       debug {
          resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "[YOUR DEV KEY]"
       }
       release {
           resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "[YOUR PROD KEY]"
       }
    }
  }
```

And in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>
```

This way you only have one AndroidManifest.xml and you set value based on your build type. Hope this helps.

Comment: How will the app know which key to use?

Comment: Easy as `getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_api_key)` and then depending on your Build Variant _debug_ / _release_ android studio will automatically get the right one

Comment: Very clean solution, my favorite.