# android map application release is not woking on device

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, release-mode

I have Android Map Application v2 and Now I Have to Publish it on Play Store and for this i have fllowed these steps.But When I Install the app Map doesn't show on device.Here are the steps.

```
Step : 1 Right Click Project->Export Application->Select you Project->Next->Select new Keystore -> Complete all rest Steps
Step : 2 Note down your Alias name and Password given.
Step : 3 Now if you Complete all process of Filling Details you will get one .apk file and keystore file in you stored location.
Step : 4 Now Again Right Click Project->Export Application->Select you Project->Next->Use Existing Keystore -> Give location and password->Next
Step : 5 Now you alias name will comes in your Drop Down->Select it -> Enter Password -> Next
Step : 6 It will ask for location to store your final .apk file.
Step : 7 Select your location and store.
Step : 8 Now this Final .apk file is Your Signed Application.
```

After Following these steps i Run the Apk On My Device But It Don't Shows the map.Plz Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141008/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show map on device with release apk you must use Release map Api key your project.

[Android: automatically choose debug/release Maps v2 api key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141008/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key)

Comment: Sir I have Created the release keystore till step 3.Now How Can I Get SHA from this keystore

Comment: Simple as you get SHA1 using debugkeystor

Answer (score 0):

When you publish an app It will use a different keystore than the debug keystore so you need to redo the steps to authenticate with google with the keystore your using to sign your apps.