# Google Maps displaying blank screen in release apk, working fine in debug mode

Tags: android, google-maps, release

Developed an application which uses Google Maps for displaying few locations which are obtained from our services.

app-debug.apk : Google Map working fine and displaying all locations.

app-release.apk : Google Map is displaying like a blank screen with Google water mak at bottom left corner.

Please helpme regarding this....

its worked fine till day before yesterday..... but now its not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmlGy.png)

Comment: are u using proguard?

Comment: Are you using signed api key for release mode?

Answer (score 2):

Debug SHA-1 certificate fingerprint will be different from production(signed) SHA-1 certificate fingerprint , so you need to set both debug SHA-1 fingerprint and production(signed) keystore SHA-1 fingerprint for same package.

To get Keystore SHA-1 fingerprint you can use following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

go to location of your keystore from terminal and replace mystore.keystore with your generated keystore.

Comment: Yes, I did the same but still my code is not working

Comment: check your package name, set both certificate fingerprint for your project package name and place API key in AndroidManifest.xml and try

Answer (score 0):

you should add api key for both mode debug and release mode as discussed here

[api key for dubug and release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141008/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key)

Comment: We can add both fingerprints to single key.
<debug SHA1>:<package name>
<release SHA1>:<package name>