# Release API-KEY does not display the MAP or google Places

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, api-key

I have created a Beta version as a test of my Demo on google store.

I have generated a signed APK using  android-studio. After testing the debugg version seccessfuly, now I am testing the release one from google store.

I have used this way according to this tutorial to use both keys :
[android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141008/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key/17141660#17141660)

```
Manifest :
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${mapApiKeyValue}" />
```

In Gradle :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapApiKeyValue:"GHjaSyAjlyp3O831lgaonHMXsd-_DpQ3002xxxxx"]
    }

    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapApiKeyValue:"AIzaSyAuMGDLr2HeuRed4JA0CrdYYdZRjyyyyy"]
    }
}
```

It works for me but if I use fingerprint / using my package-name and SHA1, so the map can not be displayed on the activity

is there any other configuration ?

- this option makes my map invisible on the activity :
  [screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQxk.png)
- the key is enabled show here :
  [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVGHm.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Published App on Play Store can't communicate with Google Maps API and Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671778/published-app-on-play-store-cant-communicate-with-google-maps-api-and-facebook)

Comment: thanks, I have used now the SHA-1 of certificate fingerprint of google. it works, before I have used my android-project-SHA-1. [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwSxa.png)