# Google Map not working in Release APK, but working correct in Debug APK

Tags: android, google-maps

I've implemented Google Map in my application. Everything works correct in Debug version.  But as soon I generate Release APK, Google Map is not working

I have done All process for (SHA-1 key and package), but I'm facing the same problem.

I have seen the "questions that may already have your answer", but I'm not satisfied with those answers.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Debug certificate is different from your production certificate. You need to add both to your Google Maps key entry in your API console as seaparate row - each with the same packageId, but naturally different SHA1 hash.

OR

Maybe you have two google_maps_api.xml files, one in the app/src/debug/res/values folder and the other in the app/src/release/res/values folder, but only the debug one contains your API key.

Comment: The second option helped. Really stupid mistake. But thanks. 

Comment: Second one helped, Thanks.

Comment: second Helped ThanQ

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this steps to working google map in both debug and release mode
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141660/8118033