# My flutter app not fetching data from api in release.apk but works in debug mode

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

My Android app in flutter not fetching data from API in release.apk but works fine in debug mode or in the emulator, I tried everything I also added internet permission in my AndroidManifest.xml code but nothing works for me. Please kindly solve the issue I am new to flutter and Android development.

AndroidManifest in app/src/main file code

```
 <manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="xyz">
        <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
             calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
             In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
             additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
             FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
    
        <application
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
            android:label="xyz"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:targetApi="q">
    
    
    
            <provider
                android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
            </provider>
    
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                     the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                     while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                     to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                    />
    
                <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                     Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                     screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                     gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                     Flutter's first frame. -->
    
                <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                    />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
    
            </activity>
            <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
                 This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Comment: thanks ..please answer my question

Comment: Have you found any solution. I am also stuck in the the same point?

Comment: what is your API (http/https)?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding **shrinkResources false** and  **minifyEnabled false** in the android/app/build.gradle file under **buildTypes**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to add permission to access network on release app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please add the permission and it will solve your current issue

Answer (score 0):

Please hide your api key first.
The api not working must be because of api keys. You need different ones . Follow this

[Android: automatically choose debug/release Maps v2 api key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141008/android-automatically-choose-debug-release-maps-v2-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Android manifest for the release app declares the INTERNET permission. See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking