# Can we have multiple API key for google API in same project

Tags: android

Can we use multiple google API key in same project, so that one API key can be used for google map and another for google places.

Thanks
Anil

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606084/multiple-api-keys-in-the-same-android-project

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it. Though it works in cases. Take a look at following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141660/1120126

Comment: I don't want to add two google api key for debug and release version of app. I wanted to add these two api key for calling map api and google places API.